# How to concatenate _ in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

_ in vb.net is used for line continuation. How to concatenate _ in a text.

I am trying this

```
 aPath.ExeConfigFilename = strAppPath & "\" & Environment.UserName.ToString & Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString &_& xyzConstants.CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: Enclose _ in quotes: `"_"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
aPath.ExeConfigFilename = strAppPath & "\" & Environment.UserName.ToString &
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString &_& xyzConstants.CONFIG_FILE
```

to this:

```
aPath.ExeConfigFilename = strAppPath & "\" & Environment.UserName.ToString &
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString & "_" & xyzConstants.CONFIG_FILE
```